# Read empty string value as object with null properties using Jackson

Tags: android, kotlin, jackson, retrofit, okhttp

I have an API request to handle that sometimes returns with code 200 and a value of something like

`{ "key" : "value" }`

But in some cases, API might return with code 204. Handling this is [a whole other story](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2867), but I end up with an interceptor that replaces a response body with an empty string, so it won't throw NoSuchElementException.

Now I want to handle the result with Jackson in a way, that in a case of 200 I would get an object of class A described like this:

```
class A(@JsonProperty("key") val value: String?)
```

But in the case of 204 and empty body response, I would like to get an instance of A with `value` property equals `null`.

I've tried adding a custom deserialiser, but I get the following exception even before my deserialiser code is executed:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]
```

This is kind of obvious since there's no top-level JSON object in an empty string.

Is there a way I can achieve desired behaviour using Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Jackson but I notice you said

> I end up with an interceptor that replaces a response body with an empty string

Can't you just then instead of empty string return `"{ \"key\" : null }"` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the idea but, unfortunately, this would cause a problem for other requests that use same okhttp client, there are a ton of them in the app :)
Creating separate okhttp clients with different interceptors for different requests doesn't seem like a good solution